# how to retrieve from cookies specified data? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

im currently working on a simple todo list. I store the tasks in cookies and when the web page reloads i retrieve my previous tasks from the cookies. However i cannot save there my tasks as completed, i.e. the tasks that i marked as complete.

```
function toHTML(id, text) {

    return '<div class="todo" id="' + id + '">' +
        '<div id="' + cbid + '"><input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/></div>' +
        '<div class="todo_description" contentEditable = "true">' +
            text +
        '</div>' +
        '<img src = "sun-icon.gif" class="close" title = "Delete the Task" />' +
    '</div>';
}
```

When i press checkbox the div with class = "todo" gets class = "checked" and the text (todo_description) inside this div becomes crossed, also the div with class="todo" itself gets another color.

```
$('#item-' + counter +' .check_todo').unbind('click');
    $('#item-' + counter +' .check_todo').click( function() {   
        var todo = $(this).parent().parent();
        todo.toggleClass('checked');

    });
```

When i reload the page i see my previous tasks but not completed tasks, because i retrieve from cookies only text:

```
 function get_cookies_array(){ 

        var cookies = { };
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {

            var split = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                var name_value = split[i].split("=");
                name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
                cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
            } 
        }
        return cookies;   
    }
```

//here i display my tasks

```
var cookies = get_cookies_array();
        var i = 0;
        for(var name in cookies) {
            $('.todo_list').prepend(toHTML('item-' + (i++), cookies[name]));
             }
```

I tried to check for the class "checked" like 
`if $(cookies[name]).hasClass('checked') 
      { make stylings for this div}` 
but this doesnt work, i need to check for div with class = "todo" which becomes "todo checked" when i press checkbox.

I'd appriciate if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if checkbox is checked you can try :

```
$('#id_checkbox').is(':checked');
```

if you want to get your cookie without reloading your page you can setTimeout between the set and the get of cookiees